# How could I handle superclass and subclass cases

Tags: python

**Problem statement:**

I have 100s of py files which defines pydantic schema. Suddenly I need to treat empty string as None. I am expecting minimal changes across all the files.

**Approach I implemented:**

I created an inherited class such as

```
class ConstrainedStr(str):
        @classmethod
def __get_validators__(cls):
    yield cls.validate

@classmethod
def validate(cls, v: str, field: Field) -> Optional[str]:
    v = v.strip()
    if v == "":
        return None
    return v
```

Then, in all the py files I just added an import statement

```
from package.module import ConstrainedStr as str
```

Luckily, It worked at the first sight. But I ended up with an issue where I have a function

**User file:**

```
from package.module import ConstrainedStr as str

def validate(cls, value:str): //sample value 'asd'
    if isinstance(value, str):
        validation_rule()
```

Here, this conditional statement failed.

**Question**

1. How could I avoid major changes to achieve this? Is there a way?
2. Why that isinstance check failed. Constrainedstr is also a str right? Is my understanding wrong?

**When I digged into this further,** just to understand the behaviour for the question #2, I found the below.

```
type(ConstrainedStr)
```

return `type<class>`.

```
`type('123')`
```

returns `type<str>`

But when I check the `builtins` package, `str` is also a class. But type function returns the type for `str` as `str` but for `ConstrainedStr` as `class`. Hence, My question #2 popped up.

Another example:

```
class A(int):
    pass

isinstance(2, A)
# False
```

This is my #2 question.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what "issue" you're having, and exactly how the conditional statement "failed". Provide a traceback and/or sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @blhsing I just added my further analysis.

Comment: It's still unclear exactly how you reproduce a "failed" condition. As it is, passing `'asd'` to `validate` makes the conditional statement `if isinstance(value, str):` evaluate as true, so I don't see what your issue really is. Please update your question with a minimal, complete, reproducible example.

Comment: @blhsing Did you miss the `from package.module import ConstrainedStr as str`?

Comment: @wjandrea I see. Having those two statements as two separate sentences confused me. But I get it now.

Comment: @blhsing It would help to see a [mre] though. For example, `validation_rule` is not defined, `cls` is never used, and `//` is invalid syntax. I can get past them of course, but it's distracting. @gibbs please make an MRE

Comment: What's `constrainedstr`? Is that a typo of `ConstrainedStr`? That would explain why you got "class" in the output.

Comment: Wait but why would you run `type(ConstrainedStr)`? You already know it's a class because you defined it that way...

Comment: I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While an instance of a subclass is automatically an instance of the base class, the reverse isn't true. This is analogous to that every cat is a mammal, but not every mammal is a cat.

Similarly, since `ConstrainedStr` is a subclass of `str`, an instance of the child class `ConstrainedStr` is automatically an instance of the base class `str`, while conversely an instance of the base class `str`, such as `'asd'`, cannot automatically be considered an instance of a child class such as `ConstrainedStr`.

To force a reverse instance check to be also true, you can customize the behavior of `isinstance` by defining [`__instancecheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__) on a metaclass. Also customize `issubclass` by defining [`__subclasscheck___`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__subclasscheck__) to keep the relationships consistent.

To achieve the desired behavior, your custom `__instancecheck__` should return `True` if the given instance is an instance of any of the base classes:

```
class SubstitutableMeta(type):
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        return any(isinstance(instance, base) for base in cls.__bases__)

    def __subclasscheck__(cls, subclass):
        return any(issubclass(subclass, base) for base in cls.__bases__)

class ConstrainedStr(str, metaclass=SubstitutableMeta):
    pass

print(isinstance('asd', ConstrainedStr)) # outputs True
```

Comment: Thanks @bihsing, Could you help me to understand why value `asd` is not `ConstrainedStr`? I understand the solution but underlying what's happening when this customisation is not in place.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer with better explanations then.